# Eclipse won't start -- possible due to new JRE install

Tags: eclipse, startup

**Environment:**

```
Windows XP
Eclipse Java EE Juno
```

One day I tried starting Eclipse:
I clicked my shortcut to Eclipse
The usual splash screen and workspace chooser appeared.
I choose a workspace.
I got the following error:

```
An error has occurred. See the log file
C:\local-work\Java\.metadata\.log
```

The log file contains a long list of exceptions. See end of this posting for complete listing.

The last thing I remember doing that might have caused this problem was downloading a new version of the jre (jre1.6.0_01) through one of those automatic download popups from Oracle.

I tried looking in the jre directory but it was corrupted so I downloaded it again.
I got the same error when starting Eclipse so I uninstalled Eclipse then installed it again but the issue persists. I've also tried creating a new workspace.

Additional information:
I was using JDK 1.7 to run my projects.
I've seen similar posts to this, but they don't contain solutions that work for my case.

Here is the start of the log. I had to delete a lot in order to post this message.

```
!SESSION 2013-02-04 22:11:20.078 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20120914-1800
java.version=1.7.0_13
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-02-04 22:11:53.187
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (76).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: Currency data is possibly corrupted
    at java.util.Currency$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.Currency.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.debug.EclipseDebugTrace.<clinit>(EclipseDebugTrace.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.debug.FrameworkDebugOptions.setFile(FrameworkDebugOptions.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.createLocation(DataArea.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.initializeLocation(DataArea.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.assertLocationInitialized(DataArea.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.getStateLocation(DataArea.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.getStateLocation(InternalPlatform.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin.getStateLocation(Plugin.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.LocalMetaArea.<init>(LocalMetaArea.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 28 more
Root exception:
java.lang.InternalError: Currency data is possibly corrupted
    at java.util.Currency$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.Currency.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.debug.EclipseDebugTrace.<clinit>(EclipseDebugTrace.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.debug.FrameworkDebugOptions.setFile(FrameworkDebugOptions.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.createLocation(DataArea.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.initializeLocation(DataArea.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.assertLocationInitialized(DataArea.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.getStateLocation(DataArea.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.getStateLocation(InternalPlatform.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin.getStateLocation(Plugin.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.LocalMetaArea.<init>(LocalMetaArea.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-02-04 22:11:53.250
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/resources/IContainer
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (76).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: Currency data is possibly corrupted
    at java.util.Currency$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.Currency.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.debug.EclipseDebugTrace.<clinit>(EclipseDebugTrace.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.debug.FrameworkDebugOptions.setFile(FrameworkDebugOptions.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.createLocation(DataArea.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.initializeLocation(DataArea.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.assertLocationInitialized(DataArea.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.getStateLocation(DataArea.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.getStateLocation(InternalPlatform.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin.getStateLocation(Plugin.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.LocalMetaArea.<init>(LocalMetaArea.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 28 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.ide 4 0 2013-02-04 22:11:53.468
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchPlugin.stop() of bundle org.eclipse.ui.ide.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.stop(BundleContextImpl.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.stopWorker(BundleHost.java:510)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.suspend(AbstractBundle.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.suspendBundle(Framework.java:1206)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.decFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.shutdown(StartLevelManager.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.suspend(InternalSystemBundle.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.shutdown(Framework.java:692)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.close(Framework.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.shutdown(EclipseStarter.java:399)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.osgi.framework.debug.EclipseDebugTrace
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.debug.FrameworkDebugOptions.setFile(FrameworkDebugOptions.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.createLocation(DataArea.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.initializeLocation(DataArea.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.assertLocationInitialized(DataArea.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.DataArea.getStateLocation(DataArea.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.InstancePreferences.getBaseLocation(InstancePreferences.java:44)
    at o
    at
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Eclipse wants a JDK, not a JRE. Dunno if that's going to sort you, but it will help.

Comment: Eclipse does not need a JDK.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out my Java installation was corrupt. I examined the log file in the .metadata directory and it hinted at a bad currency code. I uninstalled the jdk and reinstalled it. Then I did the same for Eclipse and it's working fine now. I have no idea how the Java installation could have gotten corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Go to cmd prompt check java version by typing java -version it will be show you java1.7 but in your path you have given jdk1.6.
type path 
it will show you the path which is given by you. then check the all path which contains java.exe, javac.exe or javaw.exe delete it and start the eclipse.

Generally this files should be c:\windows or c:\windows\system32.